# How to get specific XML element parameter value?

Tags: java, xml

i begin parsing xml document and have question: How to get specific XML element parameter value on Java?

XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<data>
<keyword name="text123">
    <profile num="1">
        <url>http://www.a.com</url>
        <field-1 param="">text</field-1>
        <filed-2 param="">text</field-2>
    </profile>
    <profile num="2">
        <url>http://www.b.com</url> 
        <field-1 param="">text</field-1>
        <filed-2 param="">text</field-2>
    </profile>
</keyword>
<keyword name="textabc123">
    <profile num="1">
        <url>http://www.1a.com</url>
        <field-1 param="">text</field-1>
        <filed-2 param="">text</field-2>
    </profile>
    <profile num="2">
        <url>http://www.1b.com</url> 
        <field-1 param="">text</field-1>
        <filed-2 param="">text</field-2>
    </profile>
</keyword>
</data>
```

code i write on Java:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
File xml_file=new File("file.xml");
if (xml_file.isFile() && xml_file.canRead()) {
 Document doc = builder.parse(xml_file);
 Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
 NodeList nodel = root.getChildNodes();
 for (int a = 0; a < nodel.getLength(); a++) {
  String data = /* code i don't know to write*/
  System.out.println(data);
 }
} else {}
```

i want to out to console element "keyword" parameter "name" value:

> text123

and

> text123abc

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Node node = nodel.item(a);
if(node instanceof Element) {
  data = ((Element)node).getAttribute("name");
  System.out.println(data);
}
```

Comment: after adding code i get error: Error: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element What to do?

Comment: with my snippet it is not possible to obtain this exception as there is a check with instanceof

Comment: @Iweller Thanks for the answer, I was looking fomr something like this from quite some time +1

Answer (score 5):

You can use XPath

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("somefile.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory xmlFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = xmlFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDoc = docBuilder.parse(is);
XPathFactory xpathFact = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathFact.newXPath();

String text123 = (String) xpath.evaluate("/data/keyword[1]/@name", xmlDoc, XPathConstants.STRING);
String textabc123 = (String) xpath.evaluate("/data/keyword[2]/@name", xmlDoc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Answer (score 5):

I'll guide you how to do it using JAXB.

First of all, your XML is not well formed. You've got `filed` instead of `field` on few places.

Proper XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<data>
<keyword name="text123">
    <profile num="1">
        <url>http://www.a.com</url>
        <field-1 param="">text</field-1>
        <field-2 param="">text</field-2>
    </profile>
    <profile num="2">
        <url>http://www.b.com</url> 
        <field-1 param="">text</field-1>
        <field-2 param="">text</field-2>
    </profile>
</keyword>
<keyword name="textabc123">
    <profile num="1">
        <url>http://www.1a.com</url>
        <field-1 param="">text</field-1>
        <field-2 param="">text</field-2>
    </profile>
    <profile num="2">
        <url>http://www.1b.com</url> 
        <field-1 param="">text</field-1>
        <field-2 param="">text</field-2>
    </profile>
</keyword>
</data>
```

Next, go to [this website](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) and download Trang.

Assuming your XML file is named `sample.xml`, run it through Trang using `java -jar trang.jar sample.xml sample.xsd` to obtain an xsd schema for your xml file.

Now, run `xjc sample.xsd` (xjc is a tool for generating Java classes for an XML schema, it's bundled with Java 6 SDK).

You'll get a list of Java classes:

```
generated\Data.java
generated\Field1.java
generated\Field2.java
generated\Keyword.java
generated\ObjectFactory.java
generated\Profile.java
```

Put them in your Java project file, and put `sample.xml` where your program can find it. Now, this is how you get keyword names:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Data.class);
Data data = (Data)context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new File("sample.xml"));

List<Keyword> keywords = data.getKeyword();

for (Keyword keyword : keywords) {
    System.out.println(keyword.getName());
}
```

This method might seem a bit messy at start, but if your XML structure doesn't change, I find it nicer to deal with typed Java objects than with DOM itself.

Comment: +1 but when generate an object model when you could just create your own and add the necessary JAXB annotations to get the desired mapping.

Comment: @Blaise: true, but doing it this way, it's possible to generate the schema, JAXB classes and manipulation code in less than 5 minutes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The node list contains nodes, which are in fact instances of subinterfaces (Element, Text, etc.).

This code should thus work :

```
Node node = nodel.item(a);
if (node instanceof Element) {
    Element e = (Element) node;
    System.out.println(e.getAttribute("name");
}
```